# spread operator not working in nested setState within useEffect using .map() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

```
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState({
    Configured: {
      progress: "Configured",
      tasks: [],
    },
    Approved: {
      progress: "Approved",
      tasks: [],
    },
    AwaitingPO: {
      progress: "Awaiting PO",
      tasks: [],
    },
    InProduction: {
      progress: "In-Production",
      tasks: [],
    },
    Delivered: {
      progress: "Delivered",
      tasks: [],
    },
  });

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_CUSTOMERS);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      data.customer.map((item) => {
        setColumns({
          ...columns,
          [item.progress]: {
            ...columns[item.progress],
            tasks: [
              ...columns[item.progress].tasks, ///Spread operator not working here
              item
            ],
          },
        });
      });
    }
  }, [data]);
```

I am trying to add several objects named `item` to my `tasks` array. Out of the three items I have, only one is being added. Nested states seems to be quite hard, and I feel like I'm doing something wrong regarding `useEffect` or the map function itself.

Comment: can you post an example object of `item`?

Comment: There are quite a few problems here that would need to be fixed before you can assume anything is actually wrong. First your effect states that it only depends on `data` which is not correct, as you use `columns` inside the effect. So either correct that with `[data, columns]` or use the functional form of `setState` which gives you access to the current state. Then you call `setColumns` (the updater) inside a `map` which is bound to cause problems. Not necessarily because it's wrong, but almost always when you need to debug something. My best advice here is to use the functional form of...

Comment: ... the [updater](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates), merge the updates inside that callback and return. This ensures valid access to the current state and updates only once. But without seeing what `data` holds (as baymax asked) we can't provide better update code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your effect has a missing dependency of`columns` making `columns` a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/).

To prevent the dependency you can pass a callback to the state setter function. You are also using Array.prototype.map in a wrong way, you should be using Array.prototype.reduce:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setColumns((columns) =>
    data
      ? data.customer.reduce(
          (columns, item) => ({
            ...columns,
            [item.progress]: {
              ...columns[item.progress],
              tasks: [
                ...columns[item.progress].tasks,
                item,
              ],
            },
          }),
          columns
        )
      : columns
  );
}, [data]);
```

Comment: if I could hug you right now. Spend 9 hours on this. Thank You! What do you think about setting nested states like above? Do you recommend? Thank You AGAIN!

Answer (score 0):

Because data is a useEffect object can not keep track of its internal changes because the comparison is by reference

you can do such

This is how you compare by the length of the object

```
React.useEffect(()=>{},[data.length])
```

Or alternatively, you can do so

```
React.useEffect(()=>{},[JSON.stringify(data)]
```

This way you turn it into a string and do not compare according to the reference